# Add Service Refrence in VS19 that requires authentication with client certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, wcfserviceclient, connected-services

How do I add a Connected Service that requires a Certificate?

I need to call a SOAP API developed by another company. The company has supplied me with a pfx-file based on a cer-file I've created. I've installed the certificate in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" (in local computer and current user) using the supplied password. But when i try to add a WCF Web Service Provider either through the URL or the wsdl-file I get the error: **"Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"**, and the addition of the service is abandoned.

When I contacted the company they asked me to check if the certificate was installed correctly by calling the API from SOAP UI (adding a jks-file they gave me) - this works fine. They could not be of further assistance.

I'm writing a aps.net core web application and using .net core 3.0 in VS19

I'll have to mention that this is my first practical encounter with certificates and the question might be somewhat in concise.

Answer (score 0):

The PFX might contain more than one certificate.

Are you shure you created a `.cer` (Certificate) and not a `.csr` (Certificate signing request)?

Nonetheless, the certificate must be in the **personal** store and the the certificate that issued it must be place into the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** (if it is the last one in the chain).

Here is an example ( i ran `certlm.msc` and clicked the **end entity certificate**:

[image]

- Sectico is the **root certificate** and goes to **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**
- COMODO RSA ... is the **intermediate certificate** and goes to **Intermediate Certification Authorities**
- Daniel... is the **end entity certificate** and goes to **Personal**

I recommend to import into **Personal** and then move (drag-drop) the certificates.

For the end entity there must be a private key associated - which can be identified by the key icon:

[image]

Microsoft also provides some documentation on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648360(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: It still dosen't seem to work.

I've installed the pfx in **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** exported the private key and installed it in **Personal** - does that sound right ?

The certificate is not shown with as cascading relationship as in your example - is this a problem ?